# How much database storage does a Meteor.com hosted application have?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Don't know how to even work with/view the database on my meteor.com hosted app but at the very least, would like to know how much database storage they give you.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen a limit imposed anywhere, though I am sure there is one at some point. I would suggest you email or tweet the Meteor folks directly to see what their thoughts are on their hosting service and limitations. I do believe that they suggest *.meteor.com is a service to allow you to a) create test applications and b) to get used to the platform. I wouldn't call it a long term strategy for deployment, personally.

Comment: Not sure why people down vote me.  Have found nothing on this anywhere and it doesn't say anything in the Meteor docs.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: I also am not sure why. It would have been appropriate to at least give you a reason for the down vote. Never the less, I am sorry I don't have a better answer! Personally, I would (and have) started out on *.meteor.com and then moved to my own hosting (AWS).